# Analyzing the gossip/epidemic protocol

Tags: probability, computer-science

The [gossip protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol) works as follows:

1. Start by having 1 infected node and n-1 uninfected nodes (a total of n nodes)
2. In each round t every infected node gossips to b random nodes. Nodes that were uninfected and receive the gossip become infected.

I'm trying to come up with a formula for the remaining numbers of uninfected nodes after each round t.

What I have so far is this:

x(t) = number of uninfected nodes after round t

$U_v(t)$ = probability that node v remains uninfected after round t

Given that any gossip message has a probability of $1-\frac{1}{n}$ of reaching node v and given that each round $b*(n-x(t))$ independent gossips are being sent it follows that:

$$U_v(t+1) = (1-\frac{1}{n})^{b*(n-x(t))}$$

Given that at the beginning of round t+1 there are x(t) uninfected nodes and that the probability of any uninfected node of remaining uninfected is $U_v(t+1)$ we can apply the linearity of expectation and conclude that:

$$x(t+1) = x(t) * (1-\frac{1}{n})^{b*(n-x(t))}$$

Now for my question: can the above recurrence be reduced any further (hopefully getting rid of the recurrence)?

Comment: I have not seen a recurrence relation  of this kind. Then it must be only solvable numerically.

Comment: Is $b$ a constant? For instance, if $b=7$, would every person spread the gossip to seven other people every round?

Comment: Yes, b is a constant. Every infected person spreads the gossip to 7 other people each round. However, some of the people they spread the gossip to might already have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [logistic functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html), which are frequently used to model spread of things and population growth. I'm not sure if your recurrence can be reduced any further, but you could probably find some way to make your problem into a logistic function.

Comment: The course that describes the protocol actually uses something very similar to a logistic function for analyzing it. The problem is that it's not accurate. I've compared the outputs of my function to the ones generated by the logistic function and they're different. They both have a sigmoid shape but the logistic function converges to 0 faster. I've ran a computer simulation of the protocol and the numbers generated by the simulation were almost identical to the ones generated by my function (almost due to the randomness involved).

Comment: Are these logistic functions ways of making "good enough approximations" while knowing that they're just approximations?

Comment: It's based on the idea that the more people you have, the more people will receive the message and the fewer new people will hear it. You should be able to mess around with the parameters of the function to fit your data to the curve. Either way, you would need the Lambert-W function to reduce your equation, and it does not have a closed form.